# Log4j2 no appenders could be found

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

After migrating from log4j v1.2 to log4j2, I have encountered some issues I am not sure how to solve.

I believe I have managed to change my xml-configuration and the logger initialization in the class files I have, but the IDE tells me that *No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies)*

It shouldn't be necessary to add a logger to classes/ packages I haven't created right? Maybe I am just missing the big picture here, but I hope you can guide me.

[image: dependencies]

[image: Warning]

[image: log4j.xml cibf]

[image: initialization]

Thanks in regards

Answer (score 0):

You use `<AppenderRef ref="File"/>` but appender `File` is not defined.
If you want to log everything to console, just change `File` to `Console`.
If you want to log to file, define `File` appender.